# How do I determine if a specific tween has finished and destroyed?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I need to hold a tween in a variable and then at some time determine if it's finished or not.

I have tried to see **progress**() == 1 or **_gc**
but firstly progress() doesn't exist and 
secondly _gc I suppose it is a private/internal field that should not be used by me since it's not an extracted api and it could may return unexpected result or removed in future.

```
var tween = TweenMax.fromTo("body", 20, { x:-100 }, {x:0});
// ... after a minute
if (tween._gc)
{
   console.log("tween is no longer alive");
}
```

Comment: can you not check tween.duration() >= tween.totalDuration()  ?

Comment: no this is always equal

Comment: Try tween.time() >= tween.totalDuration()